# Ошибка после установки драйвера видеокарты Nvidia на Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, драйвер, nvidia

Уже давно перешел ОС **Ubuntu 18.10**, но только недавно заметил что доступно только 256мб графической памяти, хотя когда сидел под windows было 1гб(GeForce GT440), оказалось, что я использовал драйвера открытого ПО ubuntu, после чего установил проприетарные драйверa nvidia. В процессе установки ошибок не было, но после перезагрузки ubuntu просто не загружалась. Пробовал разные методы установки: через консоль, пакеты linux, официальная программа установки драйверов с сайта Nvidia но проблема не исчезает. Так же хочу отметить что когда устанавливал драйвера с программы с сайта Nvidia проблема  в отличии от других методов возникала еще в процессе установки

P.S. Проблема запуска решается если запустить терминал из режима восстановления и ввести команду `sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*` (Удалить все драйвера от nvidia), тогда ubuntu снова начнет использовать драйвера открытого ПО с памятью 256мб

Comment: Версия ubuntu у вас какая? Вот англоязычный народ тоже жаловался на эту версию граф.карты и драйвера к ней https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1715911. И обратите внимание на самый нижний комментарий

Comment: какую именно версию дров ставил? ЕМНИП ферми уже не поддерживаются свежаком...

Comment: В убунте же есть встроенная гуишная утилита для автоматического поиска и установки оптимальных проприетарных драйверов. Вы её пробовали? https://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/drivers

Comment: Я не могу сказать на счёт убунты, но, например, в манджаре тоже есть такая утилита для установки драйвера и вот там установка должна производиться только через неё и никак иначе! В противном случае вся графическая подсистема перестаёт работать. Пакеты с драйверами там тоже есть в репозиторях, но одной установки недостаточно, нужна дополнительная конфигурация, которую эта утилита производит. Предварительная установка драйверов вручную может только нарушить её работу.